# Any real use case for using the calling convention fastcall?

Tags: c++, stack, calling-convention

Have you had any real use case for using the calling convention fastcall?

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly it's faster, and therefore better ;).

Comment: See @luvieere reference article: it is NOT faster... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0004/When_to_use___fastcall.htm?PHPSESSID=dda890025ec6bb8cff3180e0f3ed3eeb)'s an article explaining when to use fastcall. It actually specifies a case when you actually have no alternative but to use it:

> Some VCL classes, such as TList, allow
>   you to specify a callback function (a
>   sort routine in the case of TList).
>   You will have to use the __fastcall
>   keyword in this case, too, as the VCL
>   expects it.

Comment: Thank you.
As a side note:
from your article, under "Is __fastcall actually fast?" section:
"The bottom line with my tests was that the Register calling convention was not any faster than the C calling convention and was, in most cases, slower. Granted, the differences in time are miniscule but I proved to myself that it would be difficult for proponents of __fastcall to claim that the Register calling convention is faster than any other"
... "To repeat what I have already said, I advise that you never use __fastcall unless it is specifically required" :)

Answer (score 5):

__fastcall tries to pass the function arguments in the CPU registers instead of the stack if possible, which is faster.

Here's a link to an MSDN article explaining the __fastcall calling convention: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk(VS.71).aspx

> The first two DWORD or smaller
>   arguments are passed in ECX and EDX
>   registers; all other arguments are
>   passed right to left.

This means this will only work for the first two arguments and only if they're <= 32 Bits.
In general I would say, don't expect any big performance advantages from this.

Answer (score 1):

I have one case where I use it effectively - it's a very small asm routine (3 instructions) which manipulates a single value in a register.

For anything but the very smallest and most performance-critical routines though the calling convention should really make no difference.